# Method using recursion causing code to fail at run time, involves global variable

Tags: java, recursion, global-variables

This question is poorly worded, but how do I make my code run as desired without getting about a hundred error messages at run time when I use recursion? This is my faulty program

```
public class Collatz 
{
public static int count;
public static int pluscount() {
    return count++;
}
public static void collatz (int n)
{
    if (n < count) {
    System.out.print(n + "");
    }
    if (n == 1) return;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        pluscount();
        collatz(n / 2);
    }
    else {
        pluscount();
        collatz(3*n + 1);
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int[] array = new int [N+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
        count = 0;
        collatz(i);
        array [i] = count;
    }
    int max = StdStats.max(array);
    System.out.println(max);
}
}
```

If I change the collatz() method to

```
public static void collatz (int n)
{
    count ++;
    StdOut.print(n + "");
    if (n == 1 || n == 0) return;
    if (n % 2 == 0) collatz(n / 2);
    else
        collatz(3*n + 1);
    }
```

and remove the pluscount() from my code, and input 7 as the argument, the code runs and prints `01213105168421421516842163105168421722113417522613402010516842117
175226134020105168421`, but it's supposed to print `7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1`

Here are the instructions from my Java textbook if anyone doesn't understand what I'm trying to accomplish:

Consider the following recursive function, which is related to a famous unsolved problem in number theory, known as the Collatz problem or the 3n + 1 problem.

```
public static void collatz(int n) {
    System.out.print(n + " ");
    if (n == 1) return;
    if (n % 2 == 0) collatz(n / 2);
    else            collatz(3*n + 1);
}
```

For example, a call to `collatz(7)` prints the sequence

```
7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

as a consequence of 17 recursive calls. Write a program that takes a command-line argument N and returns the value of n < N for which the number of recursive calls for `collatz(n)` is maximized.

Comment: What is the error message ie. `stacktrace()`?

Comment: As a side note, the default implementation will print '7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1' if you don't use the for-loop in your main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problem with your code

1.For loop in main method starts with 0 which causes problem.Start iterating from 1

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
```

2.No need to put `if (n < count)` in collatz method

Answer (score 0):

When you call `collatz(i)` and get the result, I would not save it to an array. Instead just keep track of you max count and your max n. Something like this should do the trick based on the approach you are going:

```
public static int count;
public static void collatz(int n) {
    count++;
    //System.out.print(n + " ");
    if (n == 1) return;
    if (n % 2 == 0) collatz(n / 2);
    else            collatz(3*n + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int maxn = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<=N; i++){  //Start at 1 since collatz(0) is infinite
        count = 0;
        collatz(i);
        if (count>maxCount){
            maxCount = count;
            maxn = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("your max n is: "+maxn);
}
```

Also notice that I commented out the print statment in `collatz`. The problem just focuses on how many recursion calls are being made. We do not really care what the output is during all of the recursion calls.

Hope this helps.